# Javascript - Difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I want calculate the difference between two dates write in two filed of form page. Below the html code:

```
<!-- CALENDARIO -->
<script src="js/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
<!-- CALENDARIO -->
```

---

Altro codice html

---

```
<tr>
    <td width="306" valign="top">
<div class="col-xs-8">
    Data inizio<br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_inizio" id="date_validation1" maxlength="25" size="20"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('date_validation1','yyyyMMdd')"  style="cursor:pointer"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>                        
    </td>
    <td width="307" valign="top">
<div class="col-xs-8">
    Data fine<br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data_fine" id="date_validation2" maxlength="25" size="20"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('date_validation2','yyyyMMdd')"  style="cursor:pointer"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>    
    </td>
    <td width="307" valign="top">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        Numro giorni<br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero_giorni"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to calculate the difference between two dates and write the difference in the filed name="days"?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What does `NewCssCal()` do? And why do your date fields have `maxlength="25"` - what format is that catering for?

Comment: Hi, the NewCssCal() is a script to call a date picker calendar. In this post is truncate by editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate difference between 2 dates and assign the value to another textbox

```
<input type="text" id="val1"/>
<input type="text" id="val2"/>
<input type="text" id="val3" />
<script>


function myFun() {

var x2=document.getElementById("val1").value;
var x3=document.getElementById("val2").value;
var msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
d1=new Date(x2);
d2=new Date(x3);
var x4=document.getElementById("val3");
var dd=( ((d1 - d2) / msPerDay).toFixed(0)+"days" );
    x4.value=dd;
    }

</script>
<input type="submit" id="myid" onclick="myFun()" value="get difference"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this script. I have a question. How can put in automatic the difference in the `<input type="text" id="val3" />`  without a submit?

Comment: you can put function on blur like this   <input type="text" id="val2" onblur="myFun()"/>

Comment: I have resolve combining your script solution and bootstrap datepicker calendar.

Thanks